# Literate programming in intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, literate-programming

the problem is that we have very complex/complicated interactions which can't really be described as text, so we need images to illustrate it.

So the question is, is there a plugin or some java friendly literate programming environment so we can still work with the java files as they are?

Comment: This looks like a promising request: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206756045-Displaying-an-image-in-source-code-editor